# ComputerCraft: Using shell.run() command in a program

Tags: shell, lua, minecraft, computercraft

I am trying to use the `(file , parameters`) functionality of the `shell.run()` command by assigning each word in a string to a new variable. The only way I know to do this is with `tArgs[#]`.
Which if at the command line and typing a name of a program and its arguments that uses `tArgs` to do so will work fine. But I want to do this from a prompt within a program. So the scenario is:

```
1.The computer starts a program using the startup file.

2.Using the "write()" command the program asks for a command to run with parameters.

3.The user types for ex. "echo yes"

4.The program then takes the word "echo" and assigns it to "var1" and then the
 word: "yes" and assigns it to "var2"

5.The program takes "var1" and "var2" and inputs it to the "shell.run()" command in the
 format: shell.run((var1),(var2))

6.The "shell.run()" calls a program named "echo" which is set up to allow
  for parameters to be entered without a prompt by using the "tArgs = {...}" command
  and the "echo" program sees that it is getting an argument "yes" and runs the
  command: "print(tArgs[1])"
```

I have been working furiously trying to figure this out but cannot get it to work.
Here is some code I have put together.

`------------------------------------------------------------`

```
-- 1.At the CraftOS the startup file runs a program "cmd"

[[Program: startup]]

shell.run("cmd")

[[end of startup]]

--2.Runs program "cmd"

[[Program: cmd]]

-- Now in cmd

term.clear()
term.setCursorPos(1,1)

function prompt()

write(">") --assuming user typed: echo yes
tArgs = {...}

file = tArgs[1] --will get the word "echo"
param1 = tArgs[2] --will get the word "yes"

if #tArgs < 1 then

    print(Syntax: <command> <parameters>)
    prompt()
else
    print()
    shell.run((file), (param1)) --resulting command is shell.run("echo","yes")
    print()
    prompt()
end
end

prompt()

[[end of cmd]]

--3.Runs the program "echo" because it was the first word in our command.

[[Program: echo]]

tArgs = {...}
param = tArgs[1]

print(param) --prints "yes" which is what the "shell.run((file), (param1)) is referring to.

[[end of echo]]
```

And the result of this should be like so in program "cmd" as this is where the custom shell is.

```
>echo yes

yes

>

--4.Then because functions return after completion it should loop back into function prompt().
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, if you have any advice please supply code that shows how you are using it in a program.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to turn the user's input `"foo bar"` into `shell.run("foo", "bar")`. If so, you want to split the `"foo bar"` string into a table, then unpack that table:

```
function split(a)
    local result = {}
    for i in a:gmatch("%a+") do
        result[#result + 1] = i
    end
    return result
end
shell.run(unpack(split(read())))
```

Also the main issue in the previous answer is the use of the word `break` as a function name. You can't use that as a variable (or function) name becuase `break` is an actual statement that will end the current `for` or `while` loop in which it is called. Example:

```
for i = 1, 10 do
    if i = 5 then
        break
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the cmd file, prompt() relies on the arguments passed to the program because
`tArgs={...}` is equivalent to `tArgs=arguments`. However, there aren't passed *any* parameters to the cmd program. In order to get input, use `read()`. Then, you of course still have to break that down in multiple words.
For that, you might try this code (returns a table):

```
function break(str)
    --Define variables; ret is the output, j is the current index.
    local ret={""}
    local j=1
    --Loop through the string
    for i=1,#str do
        --Extract the current character
        local char=string.sub(str,i,i)
        --Check if it is a space and the previous item was not a space, too.
        if char==" " and ret[j]~="" then
            --It is whitespace; move on forward!
            j=j+1
            ret[j]=""
        else
            --No whitespace; append it to the string
            ret[j]=ret[j]..char
        end
    end
    return ret
end
```

Code not tested, report bugs in the comments.
EDIT: Commented the code a bit.

Comment: its giving an error, attempt to get length of a function

Comment: also, could you show the loop running and then filling in the shell.run() command? I don't fully understand how your loop is separating anything and adding it to a new variable

Comment: @cmd What code do you run this function with? Perhaps break(read)? Try break(read()) in that case.

Comment: all of my code is in the question, if you could please use your example to make a working version it'd be much appreciated as your code seems to not separate each word into a new variable but gets the length of the function `break(str)`